# MySQL Workbench: How to show the columns of view table?

Tags: mysql-workbench

[image]

The table with blue header is normal mysql table, while the one with yellow header is view table. I used reversed engineering to import these tables into mysql workbench and trying to place relationship among them using existing columns, but I can't expand and see the columns of view table.

It is the limitation of mysql workbench, or actually it is possible to expand the view table? If it is able to expand, can someone please guide me on this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a limitatiion and, to my surprise, not something that people requested in the past. If you like you can open a feature request at http://bugs.mysql.com to get this implemented.